# Swift: Inheriting @objc protocols creates segfault. How do I create inheritable protocols with optional variables and functions?

Tags: ios, inheritance, swift, protocols

I am creating a series of protocols for standard communication between UIViewControllers. The idea was to have protocols build on each other so in most cases I can pick a single protocol to attach to a UIViewController and function parameters expecting that type.

However, to use optional variables and functions, @objc has to be attached to the controller definition like so:

```
@objc protocol ControllerDelegate {
    optional func controller(controller: UIViewController!, didFinishWithResult result:String?)
}
```

That's fine, but now this doesn't work:

```
@objc protocol SingleSelectDelegate: ControllerDelegate {
    func controller(controller: UIViewController!, didSelect object:AnyObject!)
}
```

In order for this to inherit from an @objc protocol, it also seems to need to be @objc. But this causes a segmentation fault in XCode for me. It seems that other protocols can't inherit from existing protocols.

For now, I have an answer, simply don't inherit. Part of the idea is that it will be easier to apply types if I don't have to provide several. The syntax for applying multiple Types in swift is pretty messy within functions.

Another option is to not allow anything to be optional. Then I can use inheritance and not use @objc.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.